# Does Angular 8 require including all Input and ouput properties in all places where a specfic selector is being used?

Tags: angular

I am using  selector in multiple places in my project. I just created 2 new Input properties. Do I must include those new Input properties in all the places where I am using that selector and or I can exclude them where I do not need those new properties.

[image]

Comment: you dont need... but u should be able to check it youself, why u ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use them if you don't want them. But you have to check in your component that everything is working fine.

By the way you can just set a default value to your input if there are not send.

`@Input() input1: number = 42`

He will take the value `42` if the parent component don't use the input